# avoid clicking on "add to wishlist" is redirecting to "wishlist" page in magento site

Tags: magento

if we click on "add to wish list" button, it's displaying "WISHLIST" page.

I don't want to display the wishlist page. instead of that i want to be in the same page. but the item should

"add to wishlist".

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try these options to achieve the functionality. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/326239/44915

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VS Ajax extension to add item in wishlist using ajax.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vs-ajax-add-to-cart-add-to-wishlist-add-to-compare-paging-toolbar.html

and if you are interested to code by your requirement,
you can follow this tutorial.

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/27/magento-ajax-based-add-product-to-wishlist-and-compare-products/